# Retrieving XML elements from XMLType Oracle

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g, oracle11gr2, xmltype

Can someone help me with retrieving the data from XMLType column in Oracle?

```
drop table xml_analysis;
create table xml_analysis(id number,soft_attributes XMLType);
create table xml_softattributes(id number,soft_attributes varchar2(200));
INSERT INTO xml_analysis VALUES 
   (       1, XMLType(
              '<softattributes> 
               <attr1>ABC</attr1>
               <attr2>XYZ</attr2> 
               <attr3>PQR</attr3> 
               </softattributes>
                '));
   insert into xml_softattributes values(1,'attr1');
   insert into xml_softattributes values(1,'attr2');
   insert into xml_softattributes values(1,'attr3');
```

1. Table xml_analysis contains the xmltype column ,whose attributes i don't know
2. Table xml_softattributes contains list of softattributes (not the xpath),which are present in the xmltype column of the xml_analysis table
3. Tables are joined based on id

Now my issue is to retrieve data from the xml_analysis table dynamically using a table xml_softattributes,how can i do that ?

Output required

```
Softattribute Value 
=======================  
   attr1        ABC
   attr2        XYZ
   attr3        PQR
```

Possible solution i can think of is using a dynamic string and execute ,but i don't want a dynamic string query to retrieve the data .

Comment: Are the attribute names set in stone (they can only be `'attr1'`, `'attr2'` and `'attr3'`), or do you need to allow them to be arbitrary, and retrieved based on values in `xml_softattributes`? If it's the former, it can be done with static code. Otherwise you would need dynamic code (most likely), but one would have to ask why you don't have a more generic XML structure, where `'attr1'` and `'ABC'`, `'attr2'` and `'XYZ'`, etc., are both "values" for the same type of node. Either way this looks like some sort of EAV model... should that be fixed first?

Comment: @mathguy: No there is no pattern for attributes name,it can be anything ,based on xml_softattributes table values.The req is ,we have set of softattributes for a particular csv eg 1 in our case ,which we don't want to create a column in the table ,hence this xml_softattributes table is been looked upon and create xml based on that dynamically in the xml_analysis table.Later we need to retrieve this attributes for some reporting.But the structure will be attribute_name and value.We can also store xml data like' <attr><attr_name>attr1</attr_name><attr_value>ABC</attr_value></attr>'

Comment: @GauravSoni - the very last sentence in your Comment is exactly what I am/was suggesting: if you have the XML data structured that way, you can use the `XMLTABLE` function to extract it from the XMLTYPE without knowing the names of all the possible attributes beforehand; and you wouldn't need UNPIVOT, the data is extracted already in the desired column format.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the combination of `existsNode` and `extract` functions as follows.

```
SELECT b.SOFT_ATTRIBUTES,
  CASE
    WHEN existsNode (a.soft_attributes ,'/*/'
      ||b.SOFT_ATTRIBUTES) = 1
    THEN a.soft_attributes.extract('/*/'
      ||b.SOFT_ATTRIBUTES
      ||'/text()').getStringVal()
  END value
FROM xml_analysis a,
  xml_softattributes b
WHERE a.id = b.id;
```

`*`    is Used as a wildcard to match any child node. For example, /PO/*/STREET matches any street element that is a grandchild of the PO element.

Output:

```
attr1   ABC
attr2   XYZ
attr3   PQR
```

Answer (score 3):

If the set of attributes is fixed (`'attr1', 'attr2', 'attr3'`), then you can extract the data from the XML structure and then unpivot. Then you can join to the other table in the usual way.

```
select id, softattribute, value
from (
       select x.id, xt.attr1, xt.attr2, xt.attr3
       from   xml_analysis x,
              xmltable('/softattributes'
                passing x.soft_attributes
                columns
                  attr1 varchar2(100) path 'attr1',
                  attr2 varchar2(100) path 'attr2',
                  attr3 varchar2(100) path 'attr3'
              ) xt
     )
unpivot ( value 
          for softattribute in (attr1 as 'attr1', attr2 as 'attr2', attr3 as 'attr3')
        )
;

ID  SOFTATTRIBUTE  VALUE
--  -------------  -----
 1  attr1          ABC
 1  attr2          XYZ
 1  attr3          PQR
```

If the set of attributes is only known by inspecting the data, then `UNPIVOT` won't work - and `XMLTABLE` won't work either, since the `PATH` must be a string literal, known to you when you write the code (or known to your dynamic query writing process), it can't be learnt at runtime.

If this is an issue, you may want to reconsider the XML structure; `'attr1'` etc. should be values, not labels, just like the values are. (If you are going to work in an EAV model, go all the way in that direction.)