# Count specific match from complete table data in Oracle DB

Tags: sql, oracle

I want to count "Yes" and "No" from the below table data irrespective of the columns.

Oracle DB Table:

[image: Oracle DB Table]

Intended Output:

[image]

It doesn't matter from which column it is coming. I just want to calculate the total count of Yes and No.
I tried with pivot but couldn't find a way how to use that for multiple columns.

Please help.

Comment: I think I found a more generic way. Check out my updated answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The [`UNPIVOT`](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B28359_01/server.111/b28286/statements_10002.htm#SQLRF01702) clause?

```
SELECT
  SUM(DECODE(v, 'Yes', 1)) "Yes",
  SUM(DECODE(v, 'No', 1)) "No"
FROM t
UNPIVOT (
  v FOR value_type IN (c1, c2, c3, c4, c5)
);
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=6e9b154994e747529b75bc81d04a696d)

More generic way:

```
SELECT
 SUM(DECODE(yes_no, 'Yes', 1)) "Yes",
 SUM(DECODE(yes_no, 'No', 1)) "No"
FROM (
  SELECT
    x.yes_no.EXTRACT(c.column_name || '/text()').getStringVal() yes_no
  FROM
    XMLTABLE ('/ROWSET/ROW'
              PASSING XMLTYPE(dbms_xmlgen.getxml('SELECT * FROM t'))
              COLUMNS
                yes_no XMLTYPE PATH '*[text() = ("Yes", "No")]') x
  CROSS JOIN user_tab_columns c
  WHERE
    c.table_name = 'T' AND
    column_name LIKE 'C%'
) t;
```

[db<>fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=oracle_11.2&fiddle=47bf7af3b728bbf4ecc087c59ceef092)

All credit must go to https://stackoverflow.com/a/45866854/3350428.

Answer (score 2):

If it has to be *dynamic*, then ... it has to be *dynamic*, which means that PL/SQL is an option to do what you want. Here's an example:

Function that loops through all columns in a table whose name is passed as a parameter and calculates number of a value passed as the second parameter:

```
SQL> create or replace function f_yes_no
  2    (par_table_name in varchar2, par_yes_no in varchar2)
  3    return number
  4  is
  5    l_cnt  number;
  6    retval number := 0;
  7  begin
  8    for cur_r in (select column_name from user_tab_columns
  9                  where table_name = dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name)
 10                    and data_type like '%CHAR%'
 11                 )
 12    loop
 13      execute immediate
 14        'select count(*) from ' || dbms_assert.sql_object_name(par_table_name) ||
 15        '  where ' || cur_r.column_name || ' = ' ||
 16        dbms_assert.enquote_literal(par_yes_no)
 17        into l_cnt;
 18      retval := retval + l_cnt;
 19    end loop;
 20    return retval;
 21  end;
 22  /

Function created.

SQL>
```

Testing: sample table:

For a sample table:

```
SQL> select * from test;

ZING  PLING COL3  BOING
----- ----- ----- -----
Yes   No    Yes   No
Yes   No    No    No
No    No    Yes   No

SQL> select f_yes_no('TEST', 'Yes') cnt_yes,
  2         f_yes_no('TEST', 'No' ) cnt_no
  3  from dual;

   CNT_YES     CNT_NO
---------- ----------
         4          8

SQL>
```

---

What's nice with it? You can reuse the function for other strings in another tables, e.g. how many `MANAGER`s are there in Scott's `EMP` table?

```
SQL> select ename, job from emp order by job;

ENAME      JOB
---------- ---------
SCOTT      ANALYST
FORD       ANALYST
MILLER     CLERK
JAMES      CLERK
SMITH      CLERK
ADAMS      CLERK
BLAKE      MANAGER
JONES      MANAGER
CLARK      MANAGER
KING       PRESIDENT
TURNER     SALESMAN
MARTIN     SALESMAN
WARD       SALESMAN
ALLEN      SALESMAN

14 rows selected.

SQL> select f_yes_no('EMP', 'MANAGER') cnt_mgr from dual;

   CNT_MGR
----------
         3

SQL>
```

Answer (score 0):

One method would use a lateral join:

```
select sum(case when col = 'Yes' then 1 else 0 end) as num_yes,
       sum(case when col = 'No' then 1 else 0 end) as num_no
from t cross join lateral
     (select t.column1 as col from dual union all
      select t.column2 from dual union all
      select t.column3 from dual union all
      select t.column4 from dual union all
      select t.column5 from dual
     ) t
```

Comment: Thank you. Just want to know, if there are suppose 50 columns like, then also we have to write the name of each and every column? Actually, I want to make a query that is independent of column names.

Comment: @HavishaaSharma . . . You can use a spreadsheet or query to generate the code.  That said, you seem to have a problem if you have fifty such columns.  I am guessing that a different data model would help -- such as one row per "YES" value.